# Querying cache by fields other than ID?

Tags: apollo-client, react-apollo

I'm integrating GraphQL into my application and trying to figure out if this scenario is possible.

I have a schema for a Record type and a query that returns a list of Records from my service. Schema looks something like:

```
type Query {
   records(someQueryParam: String!): [Record]!
}

type Record {
   id: String!
   otherId: String!
   <other fields here>
}
```

There are some places in my application where I need to access a `Record` using the `otherId` value (because that's all I have access to). Currently, I do that with a mapping of `otherId` to `id` values that's populated after all the `Record`s are downloaded. I use the map to go from `otherId` to `id`, and then use the `id` value to index into the collection of `Record` objects, to avoid iterating through the whole thing. (This collection used to be populated using a separate REST call, before I started using Apollo GQL.)

I'd like to remove my dependency on this mapping if possible. Since the `Record`s are all in the Apollo cache once they've been loaded, I'd like to just query the cache for the `Record` in question using the `otherId` value. My service doesn't currently have that kind of lookup, so I don't have an existing query that I can cache in parallel. (i.e. there's no `getIdFromOtherId`).

tl;dr: Can I query my Apollo cache using something other than the `id` of an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't query the cache by `otherId` for the same reason you don't want to have to search through the record set to find the matching item -- the id is part of the item's key, and without the key Apollo can't directly access the item. Apollo's default cache is a [key-value store](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/data-sources/#caching), not a database that you can query however you like.

It's probably necessary to build a query into your data source that allows mapping between `otherId` and `id`, obviously it would be horribly inefficient at scale to search through the entire record set for your item.

Comment: Thanks, that's the approach I ended up going with! It's a bit convoluted but it works and solves the problem.